# How to easily time a block of C# code?

Tags: c#, c++

I need a simple way (and compact if possible) to execute a block of C# while counting time. Something similar to this C++ code:

```
elapsed = time_call([&] 
   {
      for_each (a.begin(), a.end(), [&](int n) {
         results1.push_back(make_tuple(n, fibonacci(n)));
      });
   });
```

where time_call is:

```
// Calls the provided work function and returns the number of milliseconds 
// that it takes to call that function.
template <class Function>
__int64 time_call(Function&& f)
{
   __int64 begin = GetTickCount();
   f();
   return GetTickCount() - begin;
}
```

I know the stopwatch way... anything more compact ?

Comment: What's wrong with `Stopwatch`?

Comment: The stopwatch way takes about 3 lines of code, how compact do you want it to be?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
TimeSpan TimeAction(Action blockingAction)
{
    Stopwatch stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    blockingAction();
    stopWatch.Stop();
    return stopWatch.Elapsed;
}
```

Usage:

```
var elapsed = TimeAction(() =>
    {
        //Code to time
    });
```

---

Based on your sample code (and usage of `GetTickCount`) you might want to return `ElapsedTicks` instead of `Elapsed`.

Comment: Provided obviously that `action` is blocking (i.e. not async).

Comment: System.Diagnostics is not "used" by default.  And it would be 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()', not 'new StopWatch.StartNew()'.

Comment: What I meant was, StartNew() is a static method, so there shouldn't be a "new" keyword before it.

Comment: Philip: Oops, that was left over from when i created a new one and then started it.

Answer (score 6):

```
public double TimeCall(Action actionToExecute)
{
   double elapsed = 0;

   if (actionToExecute != null)
   {
      var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      actionToExecute.Invoke();
      elapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
   }

   return elapsed;
}
```

**How-to use:**

```
var elapsed = TimeCall( () => { foreach( ... ) } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the stopwatch way, but C# has lambdas too, so it should be easy enough to implement something similar to time_call().